# iPad Air 2 iOS 9/9.0.1 multitasking split view won't work

Tags: ios, ipad

My IPad Air 2 (model number: MGKM2LL/A,  Apple iPad Air 2 ‑ Wi‑Fi ‑ 64 GB ‑ 9.7" ‑ Silver) will not go into split view mode half of the screen, it will only go to the smaller bar 1/3 of the screen. I used the split view mode once but now the slide bar doesn't show up, I can't make the smaller bar get more than 1/3 of the screen, and I can't use two apps simultaneously. This problem occurred when my iPad was on iOS 9 and I updated it again to iOS 9.0.1 and the problem is still happening.

Answer (score 1):

after activating the "Slide Over" 1/3 pane, drag the split edge to center of screen

Comment: I'm still not in the habit of making the split permanent by dragging it. Nice for a +1

Answer (score 0):

There's a quite simple way since recently.

1. Get in the situation where you have some app in "1/3 of the screen" (which I think you mean is Slide Over).
2. Click on the three dots at the top of that window

[image]

3. Then, it should propose options, click on "Split View".

[image]

4. After another sub-menu has opened, click on the side where you want your window to be.

[image]